# Interstitial test ad closes itself in Android Studio. Is this normal?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, interstitial

I am developing a simple application, only one activity, in Android Studio. I have implemented interstitial test banners sucessfully, which are presented from time to time (60 seconds in my development environment). The banner indicating that everything works is presented but only for a second, or less, and closes itself. And so on. There are times when it stays on screen for longer (it gives me time to close manually). Is this normal with test banners? That behavior is the same in emulator and physical phone.

Here is the code used:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prepareAd();

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("hello", "world");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                        } else {
                           Log.d("TAG"," Interstitial not loaded");
                        }

                        prepareAd();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 10, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void  prepareAd() {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

Is this behavior normal when testing banners in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question.

The ads were closing because there was some overlapping due to the way scheduleatfixedrate works. The easy and fast solution for me was to use scheduleWithFixedDelay instead. No more overlapping.